# Javascript for navigation working on certain submenus, but not others?

Tags: javascript, html, css

If you go to http://anderson.snappywash.com/, you will see that it's a nice looking site. The navigational submenus appear to be working, BUT if you inspect element, you will see that Under the PRICING tab, there are submenus that follow the exact calling actions as the others that do not get displayed. Specifically, under div#Price_links you will find them and you will see the others too (ie: Wash links, About Links etc.) they are using this JS:

```
function showDD(id) {
var element = id + "_links";
document.getElementById(element).style.display = "block";
}

function hideDD(id) {
var element = id + "_links";
document.getElementById(element).style.display = "none";
}
```

Why are the links under pricing not being displayed?

they follow the exact same "set-up" in terms of calling as the other submenus that are being displayed. I have been cracking my brain on this one for a little while and can't seem to figure it out. Any ideas? anyone?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the HTML that is causing you the issue.

Comment: Only two of the menu items are actually using `showDD()`. That's why the other submenus aren't displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the site and this is what I saw.

Here's the HTML for the working item:

```
<img src="images/nav/unlimited.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/nav/unlimited_ov.png'; showDD('Wash');" onmouseout="this.src='images/nav/unlimited.png'; hideDD('Wash');" border="0">
```

Here's the HTML for the not working menu item:

```
<img src="images/nav/pricing.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/nav/pricing_ov.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/nav/pricing.png';" border="0">
```

It seems like you left out the calls to showDD and hideDD in the item that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that you are calling showDD in the onmouseover of the elements it's working on (example line 58:)

```html
<a href="zoompass.cfm">
  <img src="images/nav/unlimited.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/nav/unlimited_ov.png'; showDD('Wash');" onmouseout="this.src='images/nav/unlimited.png'; hideDD('Wash');" border="0" />
</a>
```

But not in the pricing image

```html
<a href="pricing.cfm">
  <img src="images/nav/pricing.png" onmouseover="this.src='images/nav/pricing_ov.png';" onmouseout="this.src='images/nav/pricing.png';" border="0" />
</a>
```